# Setting up 2 node Hadoop Cluster in heterogeneous environment i.e one 64 bit machine and another 32 bit machine?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, bigdata, cloudera, windows-clustering

For my learning I am planning to create a 2 node Cloudera Hadoop cluster. I have a 32 bit Windows XP machine and now I have bought a 64 bit Windows 8 machine (as now all machines are found in 64 bit mostly).

So I have 2 options:

1. Create virtual cluster in the 64 bit machine (which is i5 processor and 8 GB RAM). But, I am not sure if it will hang (I am not trying to process millions of records. My motto is to simply process few files and check Hadoop functionality also dump some data from Oracle and play around).
2. I can create a physical Hadoop cluster between say the 64 bit and 32 bit machines. But my question is that, is it viable option (can I create Hadoop cluster between two machines: one 32 bit and another 64 bit)? If so, what is the process? I don't have much idea on networking.

I have also a basic question, what should be basic RAM and processor configuration for running a 2 node virtual cluster with simple operation like loading few data and checking the functionality?

Comment: Possible yes: but probably not worth the hassle. Stay with the win8 server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon hadoop version you are using if version supports 32 bit then it wont work along with a 64 bit machine but if it supports 64 bit then it will run on that machine. Apart from that you should also check with your jdk version install. It might be possible that if both the machines have 32 bit jdk then version of hadoop supporting 32 bit will work irrespective of the machine.

I am not sure but it should totally depends upon jdk as it will be at top of the OS.

```
1. install 32 bit jdk on both the machines.
2. install older 32 bit hadoop version on both the machines.
```

I think this will work fine for you and